# Why can't i take a parsed JSON object out of localstorage?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get the information out of the json objects. I got the information out of an API and saved them to my localStorage.

Well i'll show down here a part of my code and whats saved inside localStorage:

This is a function i wrote in JavaScript, it takes information from the API and shows it on the website. It works fine.

```js
function showWeather(latitude, longitude, city) {
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   //console.log(this.responseText);
   var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   document.getElementById("temperatuur").innerHTML = "Temperatuur: " + "&nbsp;" + (json.main.temp - 273).toFixed(1);
   document.getElementById("luchtvochtigheid").innerHTML = "Luchtvochtigheid: " + "&nbsp;" + json.main.humidity;
   document.getElementById("windsnelheid").innerHTML = "Windsnelheid: " + "&nbsp;" + json.wind.speed;
   function windrichting(){
    if (json.wind.deg > 0 && json.wind.deg < 90) {
     return "Noord-Oost";
    }
    else if (json.wind.deg > 90 && json.wind.deg < 180) {
     return "Zuid-Oost";
    } 
    else if (json.wind.deg > 180 && json.wind.deg < 270) {
     return "Zuid-West";
    }
    else if (json.wind.deg > 270 && json.wind.deg < 360) {
     return "Noord-West";
    }
    else if (json.wind.deg = 0) {
     return "Noord";
    }
    else if (json.wind.deg = 90) {
     return "Oost";
    }
    else if (json.wind.deg = 180) {
     return "Zuid";
    }
    else if (json.wind.deg = 270) {
     return "West";
    }
   }
   document.getElementById("windrichting").innerHTML = "Windrichting: " + "&nbsp;" + windrichting();
   var sunRiseA = new Date(json.sys.sunrise * 1000);
   var sunSetA = new Date(json.sys.sunset* 1000);
   sunRiseB = sunRiseA.toGMTString();
   sunSetB = sunSetA.toGMTString();
   document.getElementById("zonsopgang").innerHTML = "Zonsopgang: " + "&nbsp;" + sunRiseB;
   document.getElementById("zonsondergang").innerHTML = "Zonsondergang: " + "&nbsp;" + sunSetB;
   document.getElementById("titel2").innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + "<h3>Het weer in " + city + "</h>";
   
   
   var user1 = this.responseText;
   window.sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user1));
   
   var user2 = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
   console.log(user2);
   
//   var user1 = { "firstname": "Joe", "my_apikey" : "secret" };
//   window.sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user1));
//
//   var user2 = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
//   console.log(user2.firstname);

  }
 };
```

It's about this part of the code i recently added:

```js
      var user1 = this.responseText;
   window.localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user1));
   
   var user2 = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user"));
   console.log(user2);
```

Well as you see i take the response from the API and add it to my localStorage it works fine aswell when i print the objects on my console i see them:

console log:

```html
{"coord":{"lon":7.29,"lat":9.4},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":299.722,"pressure":967.13,"humidity":95,"temp_min":299.722,"temp_max":299.722,"sea_level":1023.55,"grnd_level":967.13},"wind":{"speed":4.23,"deg":214.001},"clouds":{"all":12},"dt":1525343157,"sys":{"message":0.0033,"country":"NG","sunrise":1525324408,"sunset":1525369321},"id":2322794,"name":"Suleja","cod":200}
```

localstorage log:

```html
"{\"coord\":{\"lon\":7.29,\"lat\":9.4},\"weather\":[{\"id\":801,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"few clouds\",\"icon\":\"02d\"}],\"base\":\"stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":299.722,\"pressure\":967.13,\"humidity\":95,\"temp_min\":299.722,\"temp_max\":299.722,\"sea_level\":1023.55,\"grnd_level\":967.13},\"wind\":{\"speed\":4.23,\"deg\":214.001},\"clouds\":{\"all\":12},\"dt\":1525343157,\"sys\":{\"message\":0.0033,\"country\":\"NG\",\"sunrise\":1525324408,\"sunset\":1525369321},\"id\":2322794,\"name\":\"Suleja\",\"cod\":200}"
```

I'm used to write as you see in the function: json.wind.deg for example. It gives me information out of the response.

Now when i try to get the information out of the localstorage by writting:

console.log(user2.main.temp);

i'm getting this error:

p2_functies.js:79 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (p2_functies.js:79)

is it because everything stored in local/session storage is saved as a String?
Is there another way to get the information then?

Comment: `console.log(gegevens.wind.deg);` **cannot** give you the error *Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined* because nowhere in that code do you try to access `temp`.  You need to provide a real [mcve] and fix your code snippets so your put JavaScript in the JavaScript box and HTML in the HTML box.

Comment: @Pac0 — It isn't after they run it through `JSON.parse`, which they do in every example where they actually fetch data from localstorage.

Comment: First of , check out what Quentin wrote , your error message indicates different code running than what you display.

Some "general" debugging tactics on "undefined" issues. Make sure you are not trying to access something that has not been defined yet. Exactly as your Error indicates. If you are sure you have defined gegevens when you are trying to access it , move on and check the type of it using the typeof. If it's a String then you need to JSON.parse it , if it's not a String and it is an Object then check again what you are actually trying to access and if it is actually there.

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments, i've changed it a bit. Well as you see i added it to my localStorage, then parsed it to get the objects inside it but it still gives me the same error

Comment: `var user1 = this.responseText;` is an already-encoded string. You're then applying a second layer of encoding before storing it, so when you retrieve it and remove the second layer, you still have the first layer of encoding.

Comment: Thanks!! Solved ^.^